# CSS correctly directs width but .svgs still are truncated by height

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an .svg that includes a base-64 encoded .png that I am including inline in an html page, as follows (base 64 truncated for brevity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Something Worth Seeing - an SVG Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body class="site">
<figure class="svgdisplay">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 1428 1870" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1428 1870;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
.st0{opacity:5.000000e-05;}
.st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
.st2{opacity:5.000000e-05;fill:#FFFFFF;}
</style>
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="2310"
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACQYAAAvRCAYAAACWvamgAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN 
</image>
<a xlink:href="../ContactForm/email2.html" target="_blank">
<g class="st0">
    <rect x="415" y="48" class="st1" width="77" height="27"/>
</g>
</a>
```

The CSS is:

```
.site {
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
.svgdisplay {
width: 80%;
}
```

And it does indeed display the document at about 80% of the viewing screen. But it cuts off the top of the svg. Why, and what can I do to display the whole height of the .svg, while preserving that 80% width?

In response to enxaneta's question, the code (base 64 truncated for brevity) now is:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body class="site">
<figure class="svgdisplay">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 1428 1870" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1428 1870;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
.st0{opacity:5.000000e-05;}
.st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
.st2{opacity:5.000000e-05;fill:#FFFFFF;}
</style>
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="1428" height="1870" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACQYAAAvRCAYAAACWvamgAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN
AAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAFDY/wEbzXDSmBUW7gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" transform="matrix(0.6182 0 0 0.6182 0 0)">
</image>
<a xlink:href="../ContactForm/email2.html" target="_blank">
<g class="st0">
    <rect x="415" y="48" class="st1" width="77" height="27"/>
</g>
</a>
<a xlink:href="Website_A.html" target="_blank">
<rect x="109" y="729" class="st2" width="689" height="26"/>
</a>
<a xlink:href="Website_B.html" target="_blank">
<rect x="109" y="783" class="st2" width="798" height="30"/>
</a>
<a xlink:href="Website_C.html" target="_blank">
<rect x="118" y="843" class="st2" width="705" height="23"/>
</a>
</svg>
</figure>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS, which is supposed to dictate the size of the container, is the same as before:

```
        .site {
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        }

        .svgdisplay {
        width: 80%;
        }

    .svgdisplay {
    width: 80%;
    }
```

Comment: The svg's `viewBox` is too small for the image.  You have `viewBox="0 0 1428 1870"` indicating that the `wiewBox`'s width is 1428 units while the image's width is `width="2310"`

Comment: This is really odd. I am learning .svg, and trusted illustrator to come up with the viewbox numbers. When I look at the original file, the artbox is 1428 x 1870, which is duly recorded in the viewbox. Where those other numbers come from, I have no idea. I didn't type them in.
I'll have to try to figure that out, apart from this forum. But here is something more germane: When I corrected the viewbox numbers to show the actual dimensions of the svg, the truncation problem got worse. 
That would have made it unusable, but even worse, the hyperlinks in the .svg as presented disappeared.

Comment: Here's the basic question: How do I build a container that an .svg is bound to respect, keeping all its properties but conforming to the new restrictions on width and height?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the changes in the code